# Showing "busy wait" on top of bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using "busy wait" for ajax calls:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $("#wait").css("display", "block");
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $("#wait").css("display", "none");
});
<div id="wait" style="display:none;width:62px;height:62px;position:absolute;top:25%;left:48%; border: 1px solid #2E5C2E;">
<img src='ajax-loader.gif' width="60" height="60"/>
```

My page performs two ajax calls:

1. modal is not visible
2. When modal is visible

When the modal is not visible, the "busy wait" works fine. However, when I open the modal and do the ajax call "busy wait" gets hidden behind the modal. I am able to see that busy wait if I change the absolute position outside the modal.

I tried modifying the `z-index` for both modal (`z-index`:990) and "busy wait" (`z-index`: 999), however doing so just grays out the whole page because now "busy wait" div is on top. However, if I remove the `z-index` property or set it to `auto` or `inherit` for modal then "busy wait" goes to the back of modal.

How do I make sure that "busy wait" always stay on top without graying out anything else?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/81ssrrfj/2/

Try clicking the "open Busy Wait" from inside modal and you will see that "busy wait" gets hidden behind modal (You might have to change the absolute position of busy wait such that it is below modal)

Comment: Can you prepare a simple jsfiddle, so we can play with it?

Comment: @ClaudioBredfeldt: Ok let me make one

Comment: @ClaudioBredfeldt The jsfiddle is working now.

Comment: In that example, using `z-index: 1051` for `#wait` solves the problem.

Comment: But what is the rational behind it? I thought I already chose a very high number 999 for it to begin with

Comment: Can you please add your rational along with your suggestion as answer, so that I can accept?

Comment: default `z-index` for bootstrap modal is `1040`. any value higher than that solves the problem.

Comment: @OzgurBar: That's a very good point. How do you get to know the z-index values ? Looking into the bootstrap CSS or is there a way to display an elements z-index value?

Comment: actually its 1050 and not 1040. Got the z-index from the computed style using javascript.

Comment: yes i've noticed that right now, it's different than the `bootstrap.css` i'm using locally. regarding getting z-index values: you can check `bootstrap.css` or tools like dom explorer which actually shows 1050 for the css u're using.

Comment: Thanks Ozgur. Can you or Claudio mention that as answer so that I can accept ?

Comment: no problem:] @ClaudioBredfeldt metioned it first. it should be his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to find the `z-index` of your open modal and apply the same `value + 1` to your "wait" icon:

```
function show_loading() {
    var zIndex = 999;

    if ($('body').hasClass('modal-open')) {
        zIndex = parseInt($('div.modal').css('z-index')) + 1;
    }

    $("#wait").css({
        'display': 'block',
        'z-index': zIndex
    });

    setTimeout(function(){$("#wait").css("display", "none");}, 5000);
};
```